# Create a key pressed function for button

Tags: android, keypress

i want create a key pressed (hold key) func for my application.
for example when I press (hold) a button next year the values of textview grow and when I pickup my finger from button, stop working.

anyone can help me i most use which of Listener or function for create it?
this is my setOnClickListener but i want button press(hold) work

```
nextDay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
         if (values >= downrange && values <= uprange)
                values++;
         if (values > uprange)
                values = downrange;
         if(values <10)
                  textDayo.setText(PersianReshape.reshape("0"+String.valueOf(values)));
         else
                textDayo.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(String.valueOf(values)));

                }
            });
```

thanks for your help
and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

> when I press (hold) a button next year the values of textview grow

Have you looked at the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)? This allows you to set a date very easily: [image: datepicker image]

You can follow [this tutorial](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)

---

If you do not want to use a DatePickker, you can try to use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and a Handler to do this yourself, but this is hard to do.

Comment: i,am nit use date picker i want write code with  OnTouchListener but it work similar ontouch not holding

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to hold a button (widget) and while holding it to increase the year.

If this is the case then [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ce6d97956952472/50a625cc3cef1bec?lnk=gst&q=%22Auto%20repeat%20button%22&pli=1) should help you. The idea is that you use a timer to update the ui. Something similar is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action). If your problem is just setting the date though, a simpler way could be the one suggested by Sam above.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that does not work and we take it from there.

Comment: no code work but when i hold button not change automatic number only one value increase or decrease