# android detect touching

Tags: android, touch

I am working on a simple game.
While user is touching the screen, increment some variable.
While not, do nothing.
I am Using surfaceView
onTouchEvent, but it doesn't work because it is called only once. How can I accomplish such functionality?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    vehicle.vel_y -=0.2f;
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code which you use for implementing onTouchListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)s that are passed to the onTouchEvent method.  Specifically, look at `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.  You should receive motion events when a pointer touches the screen and when it leaves the screen.

Beyond that, the fun part is figuring out how to record progress between the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events (=

If you need a hint, you might start by looking at:

> [repeating events using handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action)

Comment: This helped me I just set one bool variable in ACTION_DOWN/UP and in separate thread is used this variable for setting the condtition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your XML layout file, you should set longClickable property of SurfaceView to true

```
android:longClickable="true"
```