# Android: Seeking through an .mp3 file using an ImageButton

Tags: android, loops, mp3, imagebutton

I'm new to Android programming, so pardon me if my problem seems noobish. Here is the code that I am using:

```
ffMusicButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                while (ffMusicButton.isPressed()) {
                    mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 10000);
                    vibe.vibrate(50);
                    synchronized (ffMusicButton){
                        try {
                            ffMusicButton.wait(400);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Currently, once the button is long pressed once, it loops, even if I don't press it anymore afterwards. How can I rectify this?

Comment: You want this to seek 10 seconds forward on a single long-click right?

Comment: I actually want it to seek while the button remains pressed after a long-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behaviour you want you are going to need a custom button. That's not how long-presses work. A long-press is just a particularly-timed press. You can't put a `while` loop in there and expect it to work (as you've found out!)

Have a look at this ([Android - Hold Button to Repeat Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action))

Previously I've used something like this before:
(http://spleenware.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/auto-repeat-buttons-in-android.html)