# While loop in setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

I want to do some action when button is pressed and stop those action when button is releasd. I have used the following code but it does not work. you may check my code here-

```
 ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 ok.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            my_var=true;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                while(my_var) do_something();
            }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                my_var=false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Is there any alternative solution for the above. Thanx in advance.

Comment: "Does not work" never help , please elaborate

Comment: when you click on the button what happens??

Comment: Unless `my_var` is initially `true` then `do_something()` will never be called. Even if it is `true`, when you release the touch (`ACTION_UP`) it is set to `false` and so the next touch won't work.

Comment: @meda & @ prashant patel: it does do_something() until finish of while method. but I want to stop it when user releases button.

Comment: @prashant patel: do you really think, you'll require logcat ??

Comment: @yahska Yes debug messages can helpful while tracking method's behavior. Try tu put `Log.d` or some thing to trace your method's behavoir

Comment: Have a look at this thread (especially the `AutoRepeatButton` answer) which is usually how I like to implement something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action

Comment: @ken Wolf: that is exactly what I was looking for "AutoRepeatButton". thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is an `AutoRepeatButton`

Basically it's a class that extends `Button` and adds some scheduled callbacks (you can adjust the interval) that happen as long as the `ACTION_DOWN` `MotionEvent` is occurring.

There are a few implementations floating around but I like the following one the best:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463940/833647

Comment: solution given above is working, but may be having some threading issues. So, can u suggest any other link. or any other example.

Comment: No sorry, that always has worked for me. What kind of threading issues?

Comment: I m moving object there, but sometimes button click doesn't work there. it doesn't move.

Comment: I can't really comment I'm afraid unless I see your solution. I feel I have answered your question - maybe someone else can help or you can open up a new question specific to this new problem.

Comment: yeah. bdw thanks for your answer. I'll mark it as accept as it works on dat prob. tank you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve so, you have to set my_var to false somewhere in the do_something method.

Comment: but I want to set my_var to false when button press is released, so how can I do that in do_something()?

Comment: I guess you could pass the event as a parameter to the function and check there.