# Android - How to hold a button for some time to repeat an action?

Tags: android

I want to create a countdown timer in my app. There will be two buttons, one for increasing time and other for decreasing time. When the user holds down the button i want to get the app to repeat to add time. 
I have already tried
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action)

but i got errors

Comment: what you tried.. atleast put your code here, so we can give solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `onTouchListener`

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // PRESSED
            // You can call a thread here which will keep increasing the time
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // RELEASED
            // Stop the thread here
            return true; 
      }
    return false;
    }
 });
```