# Button pressed once and button holds increments value(continuously)

Tags: android, button, onclick, ontouch

I'm making a button that increments the value when **press once** and **hold press** the button. As long as the button is hold, the value will keep increasing. I've been told to use onTouch instead of onClick to do this, but couldn't find the right way to do so. The below code works for only press once.Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int i = 0;
TextView textView;
Button button;


@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                setText();
            }
            return true;
        }
        });

}//oncreate
public void setText(){
    textView.setText(""+i);
    i++;
}
}//class
```

Comment: you want disable long press of button?

Comment: no. i want to implement both options. either they can increment by a click or by long press the button (for faster increment)

Comment: ok have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795551/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar thanksss ,, this did the charm.

Comment: welcome!! happy to help you!

Answer (score 2):

combining MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and timer is the key. you will launch a timer on touch down d cancel on touch up, like this:

in activity:

```
//timer for increment
Timer fixedTimer = new Timer();

void initTimer() {
    fixedTimer = new Timer();

}
```

when register timer:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                fixedTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //increment here
                    }
                }, DELAY,INTERVAL_PERIOD_FOR_INCREMENT);
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                //cancel timer
                fixedTimer.cancel();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** use below code to get the proper result.

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            setText();
        }
        return true;
    }
    });
```

Now when you hold the button down it will increase the value and on action up it will do nothing.

Hope this will help.

Comment: is this for the single increment or continues increment(as long as i press the button)

Comment: yes exactly , do you want continuous increment for just one click ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace MotionEvent.ACTION_UP to

> MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

for button pressed

```
mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    Log.d("Pressed", "Button pressed");
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

                 Log.d("Released", "Button released");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
final CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                int i= Integer.parseInt(finalTxtView.getText().toString());
                finalTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(++i));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };

        btnPresMe.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    countDownTimer.start();
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

It will increase value after every 1 second passed when you hold the button. you can change 1000 (1 sec) as per your requirement.